# Heroku PHP mcrypt not found

Tags: php, heroku

Yesterday, I was able to push without any problems, but today, my framework ( Laravel 4 ) detects that there are not anymore mcrypt on the heroku cedar app.

Do you have information that could help me ?

I tryed to add a php.ini at the root of my project with

```
 extension_dir = "/app/www/ext/"
 extension=mcrypt.so
```

and I download this archive https://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku-buildpack-php-tyler/libmcrypt-2.5.8.tar.gz , took the libmcrypt.so.4.4.8 file, renammed it to mcrypt.so and put it in a ext folder at root of my application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like it's a new changement of Heroku that created my problem : I took my source project that I saved last week and I have the same problem while it was a code working on Heroku.

Comment: This is a solution to fix this problem :
http://blog.neoxia.com/laravel-4-on-google-appengine-for-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick fix:

Fork the official default heroku php build pack (github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php), and revert it back a couple commits
(i did it here.. https://github.com/jdomonell/heroku-buildpack-php.git).

Then set your buildpack for the app (I used my own downgraded repo, feel free to use it too):

$ heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/jdomonell/heroku-buildpack-php.git

The issue is caused by a recent update that uses PHP_VERSION="5.3.27"  (instead of PHP_VERSION="5.3.10") ... which doesn't seem to include mcrypt.

Comment: They found the error by themself. It was just an update not isofunctional.

-----> PHP app detected
-----> Bundling mcrypt version 2.5.8
-----> Bundling Apache version 2.2.25
-----> Bundling PHP version 5.3.27
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
       Default types for PHP   -> web

And I tried to use a buildpack, but without success. Thanks anyway, your solution is reliable.