# Push to Heroku app fails (post-install-cmd event returned with an error) - Composer issue?

Tags: php, git, heroku, composer-php

I worked on a project last year and everything went smooth. I hadn't touched it since November 2015 until today. I made a few changes and I'm getting the following error when I try to push to Heroku. I've tried a bunch of things with Composer (composer update, composer install, removing composer.lock and vendor folder running composer install) but nothing seems to help.

```
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 494 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Deleting 1 files matching .slugignore patterns.
remote: -----> Using set buildpack heroku/php
remote: -----> PHP app detected
remote: -----> Bootstrapping...
remote: -----> Installing system packages...
remote:        NOTICE: No runtime required in composer.json; requirements
remote:        from dependencies in composer.lock will be used for selection
remote:        - php (7.0.3)
remote:        - Apache (2.4.16)
remote:        - Nginx (1.8.0)
remote: -----> Enabling PHP extensions...
remote:        - ext-zend-opcache (automatic)
remote: -----> Installing dependencies...
remote:        Composer version 1.0.0-alpha11 2015-11-14 16:21:07
remote:        Loading composer repositories with package information
remote:        Installing dependencies from lock file
remote:          - Installing symfony/finder (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing symfony/filesystem (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing symfony/console (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing nikic/php-parser (v0.9.5)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing classpreloader/classpreloader (1.0.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing d11wtq/boris (v1.0.8)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing doctrine/lexer (v1.0)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing doctrine/annotations (v1.2.0)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing doctrine/cache (v1.3.0)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing doctrine/collections (v1.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing doctrine/inflector (v1.0)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing doctrine/common (v2.4.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing doctrine/dbal (v2.4.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing facebook/php-sdk-v4 (4.0.9)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing filp/whoops (1.1.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing fzaninotto/faker (v1.4.0)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing guzzlehttp/streams (1.4.0)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing guzzlehttp/guzzle (4.1.4)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing ircmaxell/password-compat (1.0.3)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing mobiledetect/mobiledetectlib (2.8.3)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing symfony/translation (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing symfony/security-core (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing symfony/routing (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing symfony/process (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing symfony/http-foundation (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing symfony/event-dispatcher (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing symfony/debug (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing psr/log (1.0.0)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing symfony/http-kernel (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing symfony/css-selector (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing symfony/browser-kit (v2.5.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing swiftmailer/swiftmailer (v5.2.1)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing stack/builder (v1.0.2)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing predis/predis (v0.8.6)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing phpseclib/phpseclib (0.3.7)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing patchwork/utf8 (v1.1.24)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing nesbot/carbon (1.10.0)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing monolog/monolog (1.10.0)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing jeremeamia/superclosure (1.0.1)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing laravel/framework (v4.2.7)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing jenssegers/agent (v2.1.1)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing prologue/support (v1.0.1)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing prologue/alerts (dev-master 961d965)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:          - Installing way/generators (dev-master 37e65c4)
remote:            Loading from cache
remote:
remote:        Generating optimized autoload files
remote:        > php artisan clear-compiled
remote:        Mcrypt PHP extension required.
remote:        Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd e
vent returned with an error
remote:
remote:
remote:
remote:          [RuntimeException]
remote:          Error Output:
remote:
remote:
remote:
remote:        install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--
no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts]
 [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap
-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
remote:
remote:
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile PHP app
```

When I run composer update, this is the output:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.19
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.18
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.17
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.16
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.15
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.14
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.13
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.12
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.11
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.10
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.9
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.5
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.3
    - Installation request for way/generators dev-master -> satisfiable by way/g
enerators[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v4.2.1
    - way/generators dev-master requires illuminate/support ~5.0 -> satisfiable
by illuminate/support[v5.0.0, v5.0.22, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.28, v5.0.33, v5.0.
4, v5.1.1, v5.1.13, v5.1.16, v5.1.2, v5.1.20, v5.1.22, v5.1.25, v5.1.28, v5.1.30
, v5.1.31, v5.1.6, v5.1.8, v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v4
.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.22|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.25|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.26|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.28|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.33|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v4
.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.1|don't install laravel/framework v4
.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.13|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.16|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.2|don't install laravel/framework v4
.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.20|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.22|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.25|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.28|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.30|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.31|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.6|don't install laravel/framework v4
.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.1.8|don't install laravel/framework v4
.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v4
.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v
4.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v4
.2.0
    - don't install illuminate/support v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v4
.2.0
    - Installation request for laravel/framework 4.2.* -> satisfiable by laravel
/framework[v4.2.0, v4.2.1, v4.2.10, v4.2.11, v4.2.12, v4.2.13, v4.2.14, v4.2.15,
 v4.2.16, v4.2.17, v4.2.18, v4.2.19, v4.2.2, v4.2.3, v4.2.4, v4.2.5, v4.2.6, v4.
2.7, v4.2.8, v4.2.9].
```

And here is my composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
        "prologue/alerts": "dev-master",
        "way/generators": "dev-master",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "v1.4.0",
        "nesbot/Carbon": "*",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.4.*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~4.0",
        "jenssegers/agent": "*",
        "facebook/php-sdk-v4" : "4.0.*"
    },
    "require-dev" : {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.1.*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable"
}
```

If I change way/generators to `2.*` and prologue/alerts to `0.3.0` I'm able to run composer update, but still can't push after that.

Can someone please help? Been stuck on this for 2 days now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason for the error:

> Mcrypt PHP extension required.

Enable that extension to avoid the error.

Comment: mcrypt is enabled. I ran php -i | grep "mcrypt support" and it returned enabled. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you are running the same PHP the deploy process does? What about adding `php -i` as the first post-install commands? It might tell you something about your PHP being used then.

Comment: I'm running php 5.5.12. Added php -i to post-install-cmd and still the same error. :(

Comment: Yes, the error won't change, but the output should - and it should tell you which modules are available.

Comment: So I ran it again, now when I push I get the same error but the output doesn't display mcrypt. I thought php 5+ came with mcrypt pre-installed?

Comment: I wouldn't think so. Mcrypt is still an optional extension that may not be installed by default. You should consult the Heroku manual if you are missing some settings. They are supporting Composer with all required extensions, but using Laravel needs more of them. And it isn't always easy to identify which PHP in which configuration is being used.

Comment: I downloaded php_mcrypt.dll and placed it inside my php folder and added extension in php.ini. Still same error. :(

Comment: A dll? Are you running on Windows?

Comment: The documentation of Heroku says they do habe mcrypt integrated by default: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#extensions However, I found one question from 2013 where an error prevented mcrypt from being used: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971844/heroku-php-mcrypt-not-found

Comment: Yup, I'm in Windows. I tried using the buildpack from the other question as well. Didn't seem to help. Still getting the same error.

Could it be an issue with Composer?

Comment: It's no issue with Composer, it's the Laravel artisan script that is failing because it does not find the mcrypt extension. And this error is triggered by the PHP that is run on the Heroku instance (which likely is not using Windows).